# Can I set up two-fingered swiping?

Tags: touchpad

I can already scroll left and right with two-finger swiping, however, in Windows I can use the same gestures to go forward and back in browsers and such. Is this possible in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

yes, its easy
open **System Settings** ▸ **Mouse and touchpad** ▸ **Touchpad** and check **Two-finger scrolling**

Comment: I just check those settings and two-finger scrolling is selected and horizontal scrolling is also selected. This doesn't let me go back and forth in browsers though.

Comment: This is not what he's looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/383968/48105). It basically involves installing Easystroke and mapping <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> to whatever gesture you want.