# Two finger swipe to go back in browser in precise?

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch

Have tried various things but I can't find a good solution to enable two finger swipe to go 'back' in a browser. Two finger vertical scrolling works fine, but it's side-swipe back/foward I'm after.

ginn seems like it might do it, but it fails in precise with unity saying 'error subscribing to gestures', and the fix seems complicated - seems to involve fiddling with source and recompiling.

easystroke is another possibility, but it requires a mouse button to be held down and so doesn't give proper two finger swipe, this isn't what i'm after.

In case it's relevant, my touch pad is identifed as 'CyPS/2 Cypress Trackpad'

Thanks!

Comment: Does your touchpad accept multitouch or just double touch? I guess you can check by trying some of these predefined shortcuts: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch

Answer (score 5):

Adapting from [Jakob's very complete question on a similar topic](https://askubuntu.com/a/144045/48105), this is what I did:

1. Install Easystroke (run `sudo apt-get install easystroke` on the terminal, open Ubuntu Software Center and search for "easystroke" or just click the following button): [image: Install via the software center]
2. Start Easystroke. To add a new action click the panel icon and in the `Actions` tab click `Add Action`. Use the following parameters on "Type" and "Details" (feel free to use a name and gesture that you prefer): [image: screenshot]
3. Set a mouse gesture by clicking `Record Stroke` and then while pressing mouse button 2 move the mouse the way you like for this action in future.
4. If you like it add Easystroke to Startup Applications by marking as checked "Autostart easystroke" in the `Preferences` tab.

P.S.: I don't know why, but in my machine I could only record and execute strokes by holding both (physical) touchpad buttons. I thought this was due to the fact that my mouse was configured for left-handers, where the principal button is the one to the right, but switching to "normal" did not solve it.

---

To configure Easystroke, you can check its [documentation](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/easystroke/wiki/Documentation) as well as this [Tips & Tricks](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/easystroke/wiki/TipsAndTricks) section.

Comment: 9yo question, but still relevant in 2022! I wanted to post an answer but this option wasn't available, as an FYI for those trying to enable this in Chrome/Chromium, there's feature flags for this now, `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --enable-features=TouchpadOverscrollHistoryNavigation` more info on gestures for back and forward: https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/td8irt/touchpad_gestures_in_chromechromium/